# How can I focus to a specific item which is in the bottom of the page in IDE

Tags: selenium

I am trying to select a specific item in a page which is at the bottom of the page. I want to verify that element is present and the same time I want to focus to that specific item.
How can I do this in the Selenium IDE?

I tried storeEval, but its specific co-ordinated which I don't want. I am looking for some dynamic command. I tried using `css:.groupTile:contains("Concentrated")` but the focus is not going to that particular item (Concentrated).

Can someone help me with Command, Target and value please?

Answer (score 0):

CSS Selectors have many formats

i) Using id. Put this in Target: css=tag#id

tag = the HTML tag of the element being accessed,
id = the ID of the element being accessed

ii) Using class. Put this in Target: css=tag.class

tag = the HTML tag of the element being accessed,
class = the class of the element being accessed

In value you enter name of the item.